# Override Java function from Javascript

Tags: javascript, java

I'm trying to run this example from javascript. This should allow me override a Java function in javascript. 
I'm getting "Java not defined".
What package should I include in order to use Java.type and Java.extend?
I'm not very familiar with java nor javascript.
Thank you.

```
    var Thread = Java.type("java.lang.Thread");
var threadExtender = Java.extend(Thread);
var t = new threadExtender() {
    run: function() { print("Thread running!") }};
```

This is the link from where I took this example:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/prog_guide/javascript.html

Direct link to the example:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/prog_guide/javascript.html#CIHBCAJH

Comment: What on earth are you talking about?

Comment: Java and javascript are two completely separate languages. The similar names are coincidence.

Answer (score 2):

Java and Javascript are two totally different things. They are not related in any way.

I would extend my answer with the differences, but that would bloat SO database. There is nothing in common in these languages.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript is not multi-threaded for several reason. Among other, the DOM is not thread safe.

What you are using is a Java library inside your Javascript. Java and Javascript are not the same thing and their libraries are not interchangable. They are separate languages in their entirety sharing only a similar name.

"Java and Javascript are the same in the way that grapes and grapefruit are."

Comment: Thanks. I can't take credit for it, hence the quotes. I saw it somewhere else on the internet but can't remember where.